What's the statistical historical precedence for generalisation beyond overfitting?
A recent work shows generalisation beyond overfitting for overparametrized systems [*]. Is there any precedence from statistics literature or is this a new phenomenon for deep learning?
[*] Grokking: Generalization Beyond Overfitting on Small Algorithmic Datasets
arXiv:2201.02177

Very cool paper thanks for sharing. Since it's difficult to prove a negative, what kind of thing are you looking for in a negative answer? I.e. if we think that "this is a new phenomenon for deep learning", how would we satisfactorily establish this?

Looking for results or theorems from mathematical statistics that might somehow show how this regime manifests for overparametrized models.

Besides the paper of Nakkiran at el's (2019) Deep
double descent: Where bigger models and more data hurt mentioned in your own reference, in more traditional statistics and optimization literature, bias-variance trade-off was noticed to become more nuanced where models can have high capacity yet achieve low generalization error due to some form of implicit regularization such as Soudry et al's (2017) The Implicit Bias of Gradient Descent on Separable Data.

We examine gradient descent on unregularized logistic regression problems, with homogeneous linear predictors on linearly separable datasets. We show the predictor converges to the direction of the max-margin (hard margin SVM) solution... we show this convergence is very slow, and only logarithmic in the convergence of the loss itself. This can help explain the benefit of continuing to optimize the logistic or cross-entropy loss even after the training error is zero and the training loss is extremely small, and, as we show, even if the validation loss increases.


In Nakkiran et al, the "x-axis" along which "beyond" is defined is the number of parameters. By contrast, in OP's reference, the "x-axis" is the number of optimization iterations. In other words, one has to do with highly overparameterized modeling, whereas the other has to do with an optimizer run for a very long time.
